# Multi-threaded Client/Socket application gets laggy

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, server, tcp

I am building Many Clients/One Server console application. I have read and understood why I should use multiple threads and I done so, but when I run application it only works fine for one client, when I try to access server with second client it gets stuck.

Overview:
Server class gets message from client which is read from clients console. This message is parsed and categorized by type.

1. If client types 'WHOIS' server returns all active client names and the time when they joined the chat!
2. If client types simple message (anything different from options)
   ,it will be sent to all of the active clients excluding the sender.
3. If client types '@client_name(space)message' , message will be sent to specific client provided by client_name variable.
4. If client types 'LOGOUT', it exits.
5. If client types 'PINGU', interesting information about penguins will be sent to all of the active clients.

Server

```
public class ChatServer {
    private static List<Socket> activeSockets = new ArrayList<>(50);

    public static List<CleverSocket> getCleverSockets() {
        return cleverSockets;
    }

    protected static List<Socket> getActiveSockets() {
        return activeSockets;
    }

    private static List<CleverSocket> cleverSockets = new ArrayList<>(50);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int port = 3000;
        if (args.length > 0) {
            port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        }
        ServerSocket server = null;
        try {
            server = new ServerSocket(port);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            server.close();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        serverWaitingMsg(port);
        try (Socket socket = server.accept()) {
            var clientProcess = new NonBlockingClient(socket);
            Thread runClient = new Thread(clientProcess);
            runClient.start();

            while (true) {
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    protected static String connectionAccepted(Socket socket) {
        String hostName = socket.getInetAddress().getHostName();
        LocalTime now = LocalTime.now();
        String hostAddress = socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress();
        String out = (now + " Connection accepted " + hostName + "/" + hostAddress);
        return out;
    }

    protected static void serverWaitingMsg(int port) {
        StringBuilder sb;
        sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(LocalTime.now());
        sb.append(": Server is waiting on port/N ").append(port);
        System.out.println(sb);
    }

    protected static void clientJoinMsg(String clientInput) {
        StringBuilder sb;
        sb = new StringBuilder();
        LocalTime now = LocalTime.now();
        sb.append(now);
        sb.append(": *** ").append(clientInput).append(" has joined the chat room. ***");
        System.out.println(sb);
    }
}

class NonBlockingClient implements Runnable {
    private Socket client;

    public NonBlockingClient(Socket client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream())); PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream()), true);) {
            //Read client's name
            String clientName = in.readLine();

            //Write that connection accepted!
            out.println(ChatServer.connectionAccepted(client));

            CleverSocket CLS = new CleverSocket(LocalTime.now(), clientName, client);

            ChatServer.getCleverSockets().add(CLS);
            ChatServer.getActiveSockets().add(client);

            //Print that client has joined
            ChatServer.clientJoinMsg(CLS.getName());

            //Now server is till waiting
            ChatServer.serverWaitingMsg(client.getPort());

            while (true) {
                String message = in.readLine();
                String result = parseMessage(message);
                if (result.equals("skip")) out.println("");
                else out.println(result);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private String parseMessage(String message) {
        List<CleverSocket> cleverSockets = ChatServer.getCleverSockets();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(("List of all active clients: "));
        if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("whois")) {
            int i = 1;
            for (CleverSocket cs : cleverSockets) {
                sb.append("-" + i + ") " + cs.getName() + " since " + cs.getTime());
                i++;
            }

            return sb.toString();
        }

        if (message.contains("@")) {
            String filtered = message.substring(message.indexOf("@") + 1);
            String clientInfo[] = filtered.split(" ");
            ChatServer.getCleverSockets().forEach((cs) -> {
                if (cs.getName().equals(clientInfo[0])) {
                    String msg = clientInfo[1];
                    try {
                        var out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(cs.getSocket().getOutputStream()), true);
                        out.println(msg);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                }
            });
            return "skip";
        }

        if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("pingu")) {
            for (CleverSocket cleverSocket : ChatServer.getCleverSockets()) {
                if (cleverSocket.getSocket() != client) {
                    try {
                        var out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(cleverSocket.getSocket().getOutputStream()), true);
                        out.println("Penguin is seabird!");
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                }
            }

            return "skip";
        }

        if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("logout")) {
            for (var it = ChatServer.getCleverSockets().iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
                CleverSocket tmp = it.next();
                if (tmp.getSocket() == client) {
                    it.remove();
                }
            }

            for (var it = ChatServer.getActiveSockets().iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
                var tmp = it.next();
                if (tmp == client) {
                    it.remove();
                }
            }

            return "skip";
        } else {
            ChatServer.getActiveSockets().forEach((as) -> {
                if (as != client) {
                    try {
                        var out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(as.getOutputStream()), true);
                        out.println(message);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                }
            });

            return "skip";
        }
    }
}

class CleverSocket {
    private LocalTime time;
    private String name;
    private Socket socket;

    public LocalTime getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Socket getSocket() {
        return socket;
    }

    public CleverSocket(LocalTime time, String name, Socket socket) {
        this.time = time;
        this.name = name;
        this.socket = socket;
    }
}
```

Client

```
public class ChatClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String hostName = "localhost";
        int port = 3000;
        if (args.length > 0) {
            String tmp[] = args[0].split(":");
            hostName = tmp[0];
            port = Integer.parseInt(tmp[1]);
        }
        try (Socket client = new Socket(hostName, port);

             BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream())); PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream()), true);) {

            System.out.println("Enter your username: ");
            out.println(stdIn.readLine());
            System.out.println();
            //connection accepted
            System.out.println(in.readLine());

            welcome();

            String exit = "";
            while (!exit.equalsIgnoreCase("logout")) {
                String clientMsg = stdIn.readLine();
                exit = clientMsg;
                out.println(clientMsg);
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println(in.readLine());
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private static void welcome() {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("--- Welcome to the chatroom! ---");
        System.out.println("Instructions:");
        String text = """
                1. Simply type the message to broadcast it to all active clients!
                2. Type \"@username<space>message\" without quotes to send message to the specific client
                3. Type \"WHOIS\" without quotes to see list of active clients
                4. Type \"LOGOUT\" (not case sensitive) without quotes to logoff from server
                5. Type \"PINGU\" (not case sensitive) to req/send interesting fact about penguins
                """;
        System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

I have tried to change design of application, which you can see here,but it still does not work.

Comment: Note on the client side, while the code is blocked waiting for user input from the console, it is not attempting to read anything from the server. You should probably be using two threads here (one for user input, one for server "input"). Might have a similar problem on the server side. Additionally, on the server side, you have this `while (true) {}` loop. That loop is entered after the first client connects. And it will never exit, which prevents any other clients from connecting.

Comment: @Slaw If it does not take much time, can you put it in my code example, please? Sorry I am beginner and can not visualize what you have said!

Comment: Why aren't you using Netty for this? Here is a simple sample  - https://livebook.manning.com/book/netty-in-action/chapter-2/40

Comment: I am short in time. I think, that problem is not that hard to use 3rd-part library! But, thanks for mentioning it, I may use it in future!